# Show A Sub-List In Front Of Parent List That Have overflow:hidden DIV

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I am creating a side menu that will have a sub-list that will be visible on hover. For that purpose, I have the below code.

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 160px; position: relative;
}
.parent {
  width: 160px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.child {
  height: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
}
.sub_menu:hover .child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DDD;
}
.sub_menu {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul class="parent">
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li class="sub_menu">YYYYYYYYYYY
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Need To Show This In Full Width</li>
        <li>XXXXXXXXXX</li>
        <li>XXXXXXXXXX</li>
        <li>XXXXXXXXXX</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
    <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Problem is that my sub-list is hiding behind the parent DIV because of `overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;` that I need also because I am making a fixed height menu so if contain more item then it will show scroll bar in y-axis only.

So is this possible in my upper code?

Comment: With this structure, using CSS is not possible. Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. Share a pure JavaScript. No load of JQuery file...

Comment: Ok. I think it may be very helpful for you: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/#article-header-id-1

Comment: That's good and what I want but in JQuery. Is it not this available in Vanilla JavaScript because I do not want to add JQuery just for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `position: relative` to the most external `<div>` (`#sidebar`) and position the submenu using JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li.sub_menu").forEach(function(item) {

  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        submenuWrapper = item.querySelector(".child"),
        menuItemPosTop = (item.offsetTop - document.querySelector("#sidebar > ul").scrollTop) + 20 + "px",
        menuItemPosLeft = Math.round(item.offsetWidth * 0.75) + "px"
      
    submenuWrapper.style.cssText = "top:" + menuItemPosTop + "; left:" + menuItemPosLeft;
  })

})
```

```css
#sidebar {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  width: 160px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: static;
}

li .child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

li:hover > .child {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
}

li ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li .child {
  cursor: auto;
}

li .child li {
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #949494;
}

li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #bbbbbb;
}

li.sub_menu {
  background: #505050;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>XXX XXX XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX</li>
    <li class="sub_menu">YYYYYYYYYYY
      <div class="child">
        <ul>
          <li>XXX XXX XXX</li>
          <li>XXX XXX</li>
          <li>XXX</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>XXX XXX XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX</li>
    <li>XXX XXX XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX XXX</li>
    <li>XXX</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For the **top** position, you need to get the position of the item and substract the current scroll position. Then you can add an offset if you wish (20px in this case).

For the **left** position, you get the width and can use a percentage to determine where it will be shown (like 75% from the left in this case).

Reference: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow).